# OR Condition of Pyspark sql

Tags: pyspark, lambda

This works

```
new_DF = old_df.withColumn("reduced_calls", \
                F.expr("filter((calls, x -> substring(x.call, 0, 23) == 'get test/call')"))
```

I would like to add an OR condition for another text but this fails due to syntax error. Wondering what the correct syntax is

```
F.expr("filter((calls, x -> substring(x.call, 0, 23) == 'get test/call') | substring(x.call, 0, 10) == 'get another')"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by wrapping your conditions in `(` brackets and use logical `or`.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
jsn_str="""{"shop_time":[{"seconds":10,"shop":"Texmex"},{"seconds":5,"shop":"Tex"},{"seconds":15,"shop":"Tex"}]}"""

df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([jsn_str]), multiLine=True)
df.withColumn("new_col", expr("filter(shop_time, x -> (substring(x.seconds, 0, 23) == '10') or (substring(x.seconds, 0, 23) == '15'))")).show(10,False)
#+-----------------------------------+-------------------------+
#|shop_time                          |new_col                  |
#+-----------------------------------+-------------------------+
#|[{10, Texmex}, {5, Tex}, {15, Tex}]|[{10, Texmex}, {15, Tex}]|
#+-----------------------------------+-------------------------+
```